# how to get the row corresponding to the minimum value of some column in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.2

i have the following code. df3 is created using the following code.i want to get the minimum value of distance_n and also the entire row containing that minimum value .

[image]

```
 //it give just the min value , but i want entire row containing that min value
```

[image]

for getting the entire row , i converted this df3 to table for performing spark.sql

if i do like this
     spark.sql("select latitude,longitude,speed,min(distance_n) from table1").show()

//it throws error
[image]

and if 
      spark.sql("select latitude,longitude,speed,min(distance_nd) from table180").show()

// by replacing the distance_n with distance_nd it throw the error

[image]

how to resolve this to get the entire row corresponding to min value

Answer (score 1):

Before using a custom UDF, you have to register it in spark's sql Context.

e.g:

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("strLen", (s: String) => s.length())
```

After the UDF is registered, you can access it in your spark sql like

```
spark.sql("select strLen(some_col) from some_table")
```

Reference: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html

Comment: see the code above i have updated , how we make it custom udf. min is already a function.

Comment: The error that you are getting is for distance_nd function. Have you registered it ? If yes, is it present under default DB ? You can check its presence by running **show functions** in your spark sql